# Is it possible to report on individual pages that are producing Google Maps API hits?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm managing a legacy site that displays Google Maps in various forms in many different places. It has been upgraded to work with the 2018 billing structure. The number of hits that we are being charged for in Google is greater than our expectation based on the site usage and the pages where the API is actually used within our site. Is there any way to get some kind of fine-grained reporting about the pages within our site from which API hits are occurring? I can only find some high-level reports about the number of hits over time.

Comment: I thing You may call your own server for counting

Comment: @LDS the issue is that there is a discrepancy between where I think maps are being called and what Google is saying and charging for.

Comment: You should reach out to Google Maps support via https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support. I believe they can prepare such report for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @xomena suggested, I was able to get a per-page report from Google by creating a support ticket at https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support. The fields they provided in the report were date, url [of the page that produced the hit], client_id, ano_api_key, static_maps, JSMapLoads, JSPageViews, JSGeocoding, JSDirections, JSDistanceMatrix, JSPlaces, JSPlacesAutocomplete, street_view, JSElevation, Android, iOS.

They asked me to add an HTTP referrer restriction to the API key before they could produce the report, but I don't know why.

It seems that the farthest back they are able to produce reports is four weeks from the present.